# Adding ssh-keys in windows for private git

Tags: windows, git, ssh, private

might be a dumb question.... but where do we add the ssh keys of the workstation to the git server both being purely on windows 2012 R2... ..Without the use of github

i had created a remote in the git server repo as

> git remote add origin edscs-npe\bzky7x@IP:/c/temp/repo.git

In the workstation i am trying to clone the link as ..

> $ git clone edscs-npe\bzky7x@IP:/c/temp/repo.git

Cloning into 'repo'...

> ssh: connect to host "IP" port 22: Connection refused
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>
> and the repository exists.

Now the problem I think here is on the authentication between both the workstation and the git server... where do I add the ssh keys of the workstation to the git server both being windows machine...

Much help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem i think here is on the authentication between both the workstation and the git server...

To test this, just ssh from the workstation to the server. If it prompts you for a password and you are able to type it in and connect, then yes, you need to set up your ssh keys. If not, then there is more setup you need to do on the server end that is outside the scope of this question.

First, on your workstation you need to set up your public/private keys. You can do this with a command like:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

After hitting `enter` to accept the defaults, you should get some files in your `~/.ssh` folder.

Now you need to add your public key to the authorized_keys on the server account you use for your git operations (You will need to enter a password for this operation)

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`

You should be able to both interactively ssh into the server and use git to clone from the server.

Comment: I managed to make bonobo git server as an working git repo for my project though... i hope there is no vulnerabilities...